# Laravel/Eloquent - how to find models where a related model with certain values doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, I have a model called `FeatureRequest` that can be voted on, thus creating a `FeatureVote` in a separate database table. A single `FeatureRequest` can have many `FeatureVote`s.

I want to execute a query that:

Excludes users' own feature requests:

```
$f = FeatureRequest::where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

**...and Excludes `FeatureRequest`s they have not yet voted on.**

```
FeatureRequest::whereDoesntHave(...)
```

I'm not sure how to do #2, because it seems `whereDoesntHave` will retrieve models that have zero instances of the related model. **I just want to select `FeatureRequest`s where there isn't already a `FeatureVote` with `user_id` property equal to the authenticated user's id.**

ANSWER:

Thank you to Khang Tran for getting me half-way there! Here is what I settled on. It works perfectly:

```
$f = FeatureRequest::whereDoesntHave('feature_votes', function ($query){
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
    })->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider doing like the below:

```
    FeatureRequest::whereHas('featureVotes')
       ->whereDoesntHave('featureVotes',function ($query) {
          $query->where('user_id','=', Auth::id())
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas()` like following:

```
FeatureRequest::whereHas('votes', 
    function(Builder $query) {
        $query->where('user_id','=', Auth::id())
}, '=', 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for two reasons. 1) It assumes that the `FeatureRequest` has at least one or more votes, otherwise it will not return it. Also, it seems as though even if I vote on a `FeatureRequest`, it still returns it (the closure logic doesn't filter properly).

Comment: Actually the logic was reverse, try again with the updated code